# Why isn't the Book of 1 (Ethiopic) Enoch considered canon for the LDS Church?

Tags: lds, canon, pearl-of-great-price, book-of-enoch

Recently, I have been reading apocryphal and pseudepigraphical texts, and like many before me, I am struck by the extremely specific similarities between 1 Enoch and the LDS's Book of Moses. I flipped to the back of the LDS's Bible Dictionary, and noticed that the LDS Church also agrees that there are many truths in 1 Enoch. I also found a fascinating [article](https://www.lds.org/ensign/1975/10/a-strange-thing-in-the-land-the-return-of-the-book-of-enoch-part-1?lang=eng) by LDS scholar Hugh Nibley pertaining to 1 Enoch.

I understand from [this Q&A](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/why-is-the-book-of-enoch-not-regarded-as-canonical) why other Christians do not canonize 1 Enoch.

I also understand why non-LDS folk would not find the parallels and similarities (in comparison to the Book of Moses) genuine enough for the Books of Enoch to be canonized by the LDS Church, as detailed in length in [this Q&A](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39304/what-plausible-explanation-can-we-find-for-the-points-of-contact-between-moses-i)

However, I do not understand why the LDS Church does not choose to canonize this text if they consider it be an inspired work with many truths similar to their own. What are the key aspects that make LDS authorities skeptical of fully embracing 1 Enoch as part of the sacred writ? After all, they have Songs of Solomon in their canon... 1 Enoch seems a lot more relevant and aligned with their doctrine.

Comment: `they have Songs of Solomon in their cannon`: Actually, "The JST states that 'the Songs of Solomon are not inspired writings.'" -  https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bd/song-of-solomon?lang=eng

Comment: Correct. So why is Songs of Solomon canonized, but not 1 Enoch?

Comment: The Book of Enoch is recognized in the Ethiopian Orthodox Church as canon and thus inspired.

Comment: @KenGraham the Ethiopian Orthodox Church is not the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints. The EOC may consider it inspired, but the LDS do not.

Comment: @Shemseger, thanks! But can you explain to me the reasoning/rationale as to why the LDS church does not consider it inspired when they do say it is inspired in the Bible Dictionary and Nibley wrote a lot about it? Why isn't it considered canon?

Comment: Based on similarities with LDS teachings about Enoch, I would say it's very likely that 1 Enoch was either written by Enoch, or it is based on an earlier work by Enoch. However, until/unless specific revelation about it is received by latter-day prophets, we don't know how much of it is the words of Enoch, and how much has changed since it was originally written. If it's important that we systematically study the words of 1 Enoch as a standard work, God will reveal it to his servants, the prophets.

Comment: Additionally, not everything that's inspired is canonized. Usually something becomes canonized when it contains important doctrines and teachings that aren't found in other scriptures already. If something is canonized, it becomes our responsibility to consistently study and become familiar with it, so in a way it's merciful that we don't have too many canonized works! :) Related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/what-works-do-the-lds-church-recognize-as-scripture ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_works

Answer (score 2):

According to [Doctrine and Covenants Section 91](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/91)

> 1 Verily, thus saith the Lord unto you concerning the Apocrypha—There are many things contained therein that are true, and it is mostly translated correctly;
>
> 2 There are many things contained therein that are not true, which are interpolations by the hands of men.
>
> 3 Verily, I say unto you, that it is not needful that the Apocrypha should be translated.

This is referencing Joseph Smith's work in "translating" the bible. The work that lead to the Book of Moses and the JST version of the bible.

The takeaway here is that in the view of the LDS church, there is some truth in the Apocryphal texts, there is also some falsehood. Therefor it is easier to stick with the texts generally accepted as good by most followers of the Christian tradition.

Comment: I know that reference fairly well. It's a general statement regarding an entire corpus of apocryphal works. But what are the "falsehoods" in 1 Enoch? It seems like one of the true ones. What do the general authorities say about it?